# Angular material table with collapsible header

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using angular material table with collapsible header. Currently error description content is too long. therefore i am using 'more', 'less' button functionality for prevent it. Please check attached image. 
[image]

my problem, when i click 'more button' to see header text, header is collapsed.

please see the below image
[image]

when i click more button, header should not collapsible. is its possible to 
do ?

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted any code but you need to prevent Propagation after click.

So I assume that you have written method for click, use below code at the end of method.

```
public yourMethod($event)
{
    // ... your code
    $event.stopPropagation(); // this will stop event to stopPropagation
}
```

alternate way is to use same line in your template.

```
(click)="yourMethod($event); $event.stopPropagation()"
```